# how to stop a thread in pyobjc

Tags: python, objective-c, multithreading, pyobjc

My question here is : How can I stop my thread from running in `pyobjc`?

Here's the description of the issue :

I have two buttons, start and stop. I have to make a thread for the start button so that when the program starts, it will not freeze the UI. But I also need a stop button to interrupt the current running thread.

Here is the code :

```
@objc.IBAction

    def start_(self,sender):
        NSThread.detachNewThreadSelector_toTarget_withObject_(self.testThread, self, 1)

    def stop_(self,sender):
        ????????

    def testThread(self):
        #doing something...
```

I would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction and help me out.

Comment: Try goggling for: _nsthread start stop_ and you'll find at least one possible answer on StackOverflow. Go on, do it.

Comment: yeah, I tried googling for it. And doesnt give me any answer. What im trying to find out is how it works in pyobjc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this the same way is in Objective-C.

In general you need to explicitly start a new thread to keep track of the thread object, then use the thread's cancel method to ask the thread to stop and finally add regular checks to "testThread" that check if the thread is canceled.

As far as I know NSThread does not have a way to forcefully cancel threads other than by killing the POSIX-level pthread. That latter option will cause problems with memory management (and possibly locking as well) because the killed thread won't be able to clean up after itself.

See also:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html
- [terminating a secondary thread from the main thread (cocoa)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642163/terminating-a-secondary-thread-from-the-main-thread-cocoa)